# Check mark "\2714" not working?

Tags: html, css, unicode, checkbox

I'm customizing a checkbox and it seems to be functioning but the unicode check isn't working... it's appearing as the text "\2714".
Here's my code:

```
.edd_price_option_1762 {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
}
.edd_price_option_1762:active, .edd_price_option_1762:checked:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.edd_price_option_1762:checked {
    background-color: #e9ecee;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: #99a1a7;
}
.edd_price_option_1762:checked:after {
    content:"\2714";
    font-size: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 3px;
    color: #49a6db;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a back slash `\` in your markup.

It should be `content: "\2714";` currently it is: `content: "2714";`

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aUnRW/2/) - the code you posted is correct - it just doesn't match up with that is being implemented on the page.

Comment: My CSS sheet has the slash-  content: "\2714";

Comment: Why is it saying it doesnt?

Comment: @AmandaMadelineSzabo It obviously isn't in there, otherwise it wouldn't be rending '2714'.

Comment: @JoshC Unless it was minimised faulty by a server-side script.

Comment: @BramVanroy Yea, you're right. I don't know how to troubleshoot that though.

Comment: Yes Wordpress... Headway themes

Comment: There are multiple different things to consider. Maybe the `php.ini` is configured wrong.. maybe you are caching the stylesheet... maybe the backslash is being escaped.. no clue.

Comment: hm I'm not very advanced so I don't understand any of that.  What does caching the stylesheet mean?  Could be that even though I dont know what it means.  Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Random idea.. try styling via the `style` attribute. If the back slash is being removed due to rendering issues, this should work.

Comment: Hm not sure how to do that.  If you mean style it in html, I don't think I can because I'm using the class that is assigned from a plugin I'm using for the checkboxes.  The html is within the plugin.

Comment: @JoshC As far as I know it is not possible to style pseudo-elements with inline styles.

Comment: @BramVanroy You're right. I just tried doing that - didn't work.

Comment: On a whim, I tried escaping the slash and that fixed it for me: `content: "\\2714";`

Answer (score 2):

The dev tools state that your css is:

```
.edd_price_option_1762:checked:after {
    content: "2714 ";
    font-size: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 3px;
    color: #49a6db;
}
```

Change it to (add a slash):

```
.edd_price_option_1762:checked:after {
    content: "\2714";
    font-size: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 3px;
    color: #49a6db;
}
```

See attached screenshot:

[image: The proof]

Comment: Getting rid of the backward slash didn't do anything, still not working

Comment: Ohh why is it showing that?  My CSS sheet clearly says content: "\2714";

Comment: @AmandaMadelineSzabo No it doesn't. Are you sure the server isn't using a cached version? Or a minifier has wrongly minified the file! But the file that's on the server doesn't have a slash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will help in any ways. But was experimenting so thought you should see this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aCZGE/1/)

Using javascript

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "&#x2714;"
```

See if it helps. I read somewhere to use HTML entity :)
some thing like 
✔

Comment: That does create a check for me that works but I dont know how to integrate that into the class I'm using with the checkbox.  Its a plugin I downloaded and so I don't know how to access the html of the plugin to attribute styles to the checkbox class....I dont know if this makes sense or not. But maybe something with this plugin is causing the problem.

Comment: If the plugin doesnot allow you try doing setTimeout `setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "&#x2714;"}, 500)` if you have access to javascript :) css solution . Let me c

Comment: yes yes .. :) `<script> function foo(){document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "&#x2714;"}</script>` call the foo when ever you require . Like click etc. `<button onclick="foo()">`

Comment: Nevermind, I found another way to make a checkmark.  But thank you!!

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using single quotes?  Don't know if it will help, but in my css I'm using content: ' \2714'; and the check mark is showing fine, except in <=IE7 where I use a graphic instead.