# u+2714 chechmark showing up different shape and color in android

Tags: android, css, unicode, fonts, webfonts

This question is related to 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082146/check-mark-2714-not-working/19082171#19082171)

I am using this css :

```
.check li::before{
content: "\002714 \00a0";
color: green;
```

}

The checkmark (u+2714) is showing up well in green in chrome on PC, but on android chrome it is showing a slightly different shape, and in red!
I googled the question and found the above mentioned post, wit the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUnRW/2/)
Even in the JSfiddle the checkmark is showing red on android.
I have an samsung J5 android 6.0.1 and a Samsung Tab E android 4.4.4
Both give the same result. Here I add a screenshot from the JSFiddle page on my Tab E[image: you clearly see the red checkmark]

Here i add a screenshot of my site on PC [image: PC screenshot] and on android [image: Android screenshot]
The difference is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These checkmarks are emoji, and they're different designs on different OSes/platforms. See [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/heavy-check-mark/) for the different version.

The solution is to either use your own checkmark graphic (an SVG image, for instance) or use a non-emoji checkmark so you can determine the color yourself.

Comment: It is — it just doesn't prescribe the exact design. Implementers are free to design "HEAVY CHECK MARK" as they see fit. But still, Samsung deciding to make theirs red _is_ a bit weird.